# Why .loc doesn't work in Python Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I get the needed row of date '2013-09-12' with filter. Is it because label 'date' is a label of an indecies and indecies are '2013-09-12' dates. Where '.loc', I believe, is looking at column and row label values. Is my understanding correct?

```
mean_altitudes_perday = grouped_bydates.altitude.mean()

print(mean_altitudes_perday)
print(mean_altitudes_perday.loc[mean_altitudes_perday['date']] == '2013-09-12') # Why loc is not working here?


# Q: What is the mean altitude of the birds on 2013-09-12?
# A: print(mean_altitudes_perday.filter(like='2013-09-12', axis=0))
```

Error Message:

```
date
2013-08-15    134.092000
2013-08-16    134.839506
2013-08-17    147.439024
2013-08-18    129.608163
2013-08-19    180.174797
                 ...    
2014-04-26     15.118012
2014-04-27     23.897297
2014-04-28     37.716867
2014-04-29     19.244792
2014-04-30     13.954545
Name: altitude, Length: 259, dtype: float64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4410             try:
-> 4411                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
   4412             except IndexError:

# Had to delete a lot of error code due to posting requirements

KeyError: 'date'
```

Comment: In your series, `date` is an index, not a column. You can look at the syntax of [Series.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html), you will need mean_altitudes_perday.loc['2013-09-12']

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *mean_altitudes_perday* is a *Series*, with the index named *date*.

Probably some DataFrame contained *date* and *altitude* columns and you
created *mean_altitudes_perday* executing something like:

```
mean_altitudes_perday = df.set_index('date').altitude
```

Note `Name: altitude` if the final row of your printout.
This is just a **name** of the *Series*, inherited from the original
column name.
The index is also inherited, with its original name.

When you execute somenthing like `mean_altitudes_perday['date']`,
*Pandas* attempts to find *'date'* (a string) in the index and return the
corresponding element of this *Series*.

As the index has no element == *'date'*, an exception (*KeyError*) is raised.

Maybe a more meaningful name of this exception would be ***Index***Error
(no corresponding value in the index), but we can't do anything about it.

But if you execute e.g. `mean_altitudes_perday['2013-08-19']`, you will get
a value (*180.174797*).

You can also run `mean_altitudes_perday.loc['2013-08-19']` (more generally,
passing any **existing** index value), with the same result.